# General API Questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am new to coding and to using API's. I *kinda* know what I am doing, but not entirely, when it comes to using them. I know the "General Idea" but I'm struggling with the details.

I am using [This API: US, State, and PR Total Population and Components of Change](http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/population-estimates-and-projections.html)

What I want to do is put in a state code, name, or abbreviation (I'm not entirely sure how they have it set up, but I think it's by code). 
They have several variables located [here.](http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc/variables.html)

Am I supposed to put the name of the variable under where it says "var request" ?

should I put the name of the variable and then the word state? Like this:

```
var request = {
"variable name 1": "state",
"variable name 2": "population density",
"Key": 'my key value that someone suggested that I not post'
}
```

Notes to self/anyone else reading this thread, also I will keep this updated as I do some experimenting:

1. If I put "STATE.name": STATE, I get an error message about how "STATE" is undefined.
2. If I put "name": "STATE", I get this error message

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

3. If I put in "name": STATE, I get the same error message as number 1, so clearly that isn't the answer either. This is obviously better than step 2 because I don't want to use quotations. I don't know why I did that in step 2.

Original/This is what I have now JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var getStateInformation = function(stateID){
    //the parameters that we need to pass in our request to the United States Census API
    var request = {
        "Name": "STATE",
        "key": 'The key that someone suggested that I not post online'
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: request,
        url: "http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc",
        dataType: "json",
    })
    //What the function should do if successful
    .done(function(result){
        var stateSearch = $('#inputBox').val();
        showStateInformation(stateSearch);
        })

    //What the function should do if it fails
    .fail(function(jqXHR, error){
        var errorElem = showError(error);
    })


}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do

Comment: I want to put in the state name and get back the population, state name, and population density, but I'm not entirely sure how to set this up variable wise because I am a n00b.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code about JQuery Ajax ( full control ).

Hope this suggest !

```
function getStateInformation(stateID) {
    //the parameters that we need to pass in our request to Spotify's API
    var request = {
        "Name": "STATE",
        "key": 'The key that someone suggested that I not post online'
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        data: request, dataType: 'json', type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function () {
            // show loading ( Example )
            $(JQuerySelector.loading).show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // this is success callback
            if (data.Error == null) {
                // api success
                if (data.StateFound) {
                    $("#StateFound").show();
                    $("#StateInfo").val(data.StateData);
                }
                else {
                    $("#StateFound").hide();
                    $("#StateInfo").val("");
                }
            }
            else {
                // api not success show error message here
                alert(data.Error);
                // or 
                console.log(data.Error);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // error call back
            // output alert or console.log or ....
            AjaxErrorMessage(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        completed: function () {
            // hide loading ( Example )
            $(JQuerySelector.loading).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

When you need API to do something.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately this does not work. I keep getting told that STATE is undefined.

Comment: @LunchBox may be STATE is not the correct value for Name.  Check the valid values from the api documentation.

Comment: [Variable List](http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc/variables.html) If you click on that link, it shows a list of variables. If you click on state, it shows "name": "STATE".  Is that what you want me to look at?

Comment: @lunchbox, If I am not mistaken, it describes the definition of STATE variable.  Try passing this data (from sample url) {"get":"DOM", "for": "state:02", "DATE":6, "key":"YOUR_KEY"}

Comment: Dumb Question: Do you want me to put that in the part that has the parameters i.e. "var request{ .. .}" or inside the curly brackets for ajax?

Comment: I'm still having issues, but you have given me an idea.

Comment: (http://api.census.gov/data/2013/pep/natstprc) I feel like the answer is here, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing because I'm still new with this sort of stuff.

Comment: Jules: Thank you so much for posting that. I'm still new with API's, but I see why you told me to do that. My program still isn't working, but it is for a completely different reason. Thank you so much!